# Swapping div ID's using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to swap the ID's using the following interval.

```
setInterval(
  function() 
  {
    $("#viewNext").attr("id","viewActual");
    $("#viewActual").attr("id","viewNext");
  }, 2000);
```

This does work, but only one time. The interval does run, but it seems Jquery looks at the original ID's as stated when loading the page. Is there a way for Jquery to look at the ACTUAL live id's?

So, why do this? Let me clarify that! :) viewActual is "on top" of viewNext. The interval swaps there places (and several other css stuff). While viewActual is on top i load the next file into viewNext so it is loaded when swapped after 2 seconds (or any other time).

Full Code:

```
$('#viewContainer').append('<div class="viewBox" id="viewActual" style="height: '+screenWidth+'px; width: '+screenHeight+'px;"></div>');   
$('#viewContainer').append('<div class="viewBox" id="viewNext" style="height: '+screenWidth+'px; width: '+screenHeight+'px;"></div>');   

$("#viewActual").load('test/test1.php');
$("#viewNext").load('test/test2.php');

setInterval(
  function() 
  {
    $("#viewNext").attr("id","viewActual");
    $("#viewActual").attr("id","viewNext");
  }, 2000);
```

The loading isn't functioning now. I know. But i do know that the interval doesnt work because i can see that in the mozilla firefox. No reason in developing the load function as long as this doesnt work.

Comment: You change the ID _of_ `viewNext` _to_ `viewActual`, and then you _select_ the element that **now** has ID `viewActual` (so it is the same element that _originally_ had `viewNext`), and set its ID to `viewNext` again … so basically, afterwards, you have effectively done _nothing at all_. (And what is changing element IDs supposed to achieve in the first place? Sounds like a conceptual flaw to begin with, so you should give a _proper_ explanation of what purpose that is supposed to have.)

Comment: Let me clarify that! :)

viewActual is "on top" of viewNext. The interval swaps there places (and several other css stuff). While viewActual is on top i load the next file into viewNext so it is loaded when swapped after 2 seconds (or any other time).

Comment: The minimal code you have shown does none of that extra stuff you are talking about. With what you have given us so far, we can not possibly tell if the error is not maybe somewhere else (if you are saying, the suggestion from the currently existing answer does not work either.)

Comment: I'll edit the original post, and add the code. I check if it works by view the live source in Mozilla firefox. I see the changes there the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `data-*` attribute to store any desired String to swap

```js
$('#viewContainer').append('<div class="viewBox" id="viewActual" data-swapid="viewNext"></div>');   
$('#viewContainer').append('<div class="viewBox" id="viewNext" data-swapid="viewActual"></div>');   

$("#viewActual").text('aaaaa');
$("#viewNext").text('bbbbb');

setInterval(() => {
  $('[data-swapid]').each((i, el) => {
    const data = el.dataset.swapid; // Cache data value
    el.dataset.swapid = el.id;      // Swap ID into data
    el.id = data;                   // Set ID from cache 
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
#viewNext {color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="viewContainer"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This works.
Didn't know how to work with the data! Very usefull knowledge. Thank you!